# Bash printing lines if line before matches

Tags: bash

I only need to print the line directly before the +- or -- symbol in bash which contains the location of the change. how can I edit this text to do so?

Input:

```
--- /opt/   
 /opt/location1:
 /opt/location2:
 /opt/location3:
+-rw-r--r-- 1 ra 
--rwxr-xr-x 1 rt 
+-rwxr-xr-x 1 ft 
 /opt/location4:
 /opt/location5:
+-rw-r--r-- 1 dra 
--rwxr-xr-x 1 drt 
+-rwxr-xr-x 1 dft
```

output

```
  /opt/location3:
+-rw-r--r-- 1 ra 
--rwxr-xr-x 1 rt 
+-rwxr-xr-x 1 ft 
 /opt/location5:
+-rw-r--r-- 1 dra 
--rwxr-xr-x 1 drt 
+-rwxr-xr-x 1 dft
```

Comment: The line `/opt/location4:` does not start with `+-` or `--`, yet the line before that appears in your desired output.  You should modify the description to match what you actually want.

Comment: Use the `-B` option to `grep` to print N lines before the match.

Comment: @WilliamPursell I think you're misparsing. He wants to match the lines that begin with `+-` or `--`, then print the line before that.

Comment: @Barmar Not quite.  (If that were the case, the line `--- /opt/` would appear in the desired output).  I believe the desire is to print lines that begin with `+-` or `--` and the line preceding it, but only if there is a line preceding the matching line.  Although it doesn't quite do exactly that, `grep -B1 '^[+-]-'` is probably sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably just do `grep -B1 '^[+-]-' input`, but the output is not quite what you want.  To get the exact output you demonstrate, try:

```
awk '/^[+-]-/ && NR > 1{if(p) print prev; p=0; print; next} { p=1; prev = $0}' input
```